# How do I create a single instance of an object per key/context/customer?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need to create a class whose instance exists only once per key/context/customer.

I don't know if I am overthinking the problem and the solution.  Any suggestion or guidance will be extremely helpful.
Shown below is a simplified example of what I am trying to do.

To keep the posting small I removed the interface and abstract class.  You should be able to compile this code

I was using the intialization time to find if the two instances are same or different.

**Base Class**

```
package com.SomeCompany2.ps.stackOverflow.question;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class CheckClass{
    protected String intializationTime;

    public CheckClass(){
        setIntializationTime();
    }

    private void setIntializationTime() {
        final Date date = new Date();
        final DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
        this.intializationTime = formatter.format(date);
    }

    public String getIntializationTime(){
        return this.intializationTime;
    }

    public boolean isMatch(){
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Class Factory that makes sure only one instance exists.**

```
package com.SomeCompany2.ps.stackOverflow.question;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CheckClassFactory{
    private CheckClassFactory(){}

    private static class CheckClassHolder   {
        private static final Map<String, CheckClass> mapping    = new HashMap<String, CheckClass>();

        private static CheckClass getInstance(final String key){
            if (!mapping.containsKey(key)){
                final CheckClass INSTANCE   = new CheckClass();
                mapping.put(key, INSTANCE);
            }
            return mapping.get(key);
        }

        public static void removeInstance(final String key){
            mapping.remove(key);
        }
    }

    public static CheckClass getInstance(final String key){
        return CheckClassHolder.getInstance(key);
    }

    public static void removeInstance(final String key){
        CheckClassHolder.removeInstance(key);
    }
}
```

One of the questions that I do think about is that when "removeInstance" is called and the instance is removed from the map, will the instance be destroyed?

Also is there a simpler way or a know pattern to accomplish this task?

Comment: removeInstance() will only destroy the object (through the usual course of garbage collection) if no other reference is pointing to it.

Comment: You need a `synchronized` keyword on both of the methods in CheckClassFactory.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @BevynQ
The instance would be used by an external class.  When done it would call the "removeInstance" method.  Do I need to anything in the external/calling class?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways this could be improved.

Your factory maintaining the map of [key, instance] should be enough, though you may want to wrap your `mapping` accesses in a synchronized block if you will have multiple threads.

You shouldn't need `initializationTime` to see if they are different - since there is only one instance per key, you can just use the default `equals` (or `==`), since construction is controlled by the factory.

Comment: Chris, is it possible for you to show me what the signature of the code would look like with synchronized.  I don't know where it is necesseary.  Is it only necessary when adding or removing or all the time?

Comment: The simplest way is to add the `synchronized` keyword to the methods `getInstance` and `removeInstance` in your inner `CheckClassHolder` class.  This will work since the only access to `mapping` is through these methods, and both are static and belong to the same class.  For example: `private static synchronized CheckClass getInstance(final String key)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  For the time being I am not adding "synchronized" till I understand it better.  This has to do mainly with this [article](http://goo.gl/PQVK6) about Singletons.

Comment: You need `synchronized` to avoid the case where two threads enter getInstance(), and after both check containsKey() and receive a false result, then they would both create an instance of the underlying CheckClass object.  At this point, the second thread to call put() would store his instance in the map, overwriting the first instance.  If you want to guarantee that there's only one instance per key, you must synchronize the getInstance() method.